# Void method '' should not return a value

Tags: ios, react-native

I am getting this error while running application via xcode. I am trying to do this, I am new to ios development . How I can use this method inside .js file ?

in NativeBridge.m

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(listDevice)

{
return  [meetingSession.audioVideo listDevice];
I get error :

Void method 'listDevice' should not return a value

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this.  The workaround I found is that it's relatively easy to pass a callback to your native code and have the callback return the value you're looking for.  It feels like a hack though.  See https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#callbacks